# Cuda and Nvidia Driver Installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I am about to loose my mind !

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My computer has an integrated Intel VGA and a GPU which is Nvidia GTX 1070. As you can predict, I installed the latest Nvidia GPU driver (390.48) and CUDA 9.1 respectively. I also did vice versa. However both sequences ended up with problem. (I applied almost 10 methods from the internet, especially NVIDIA CUDA installation guide for Linux) Here are the steps that I applied:

1) I installed Nvidia GPU driver version of 390.48 from nvidia.com. According to https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07?_pjax=%23gist-pjax-container (via run file). That installation was completed without any problem and I was able to use my GPU. Afterwards, I installed CUDA 9.1 regarding https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html. However, after installation of CUDA, I got a few problems which are;

By the way, I applied this installation sequence a few times.So, the problems that I indicated below are the result of trials. (for each trial, I always formatted the disk and reinstalled Ubuntu)

- System installation failed because of nvidia driver version of 387 although I installed version of 390.
- After Installation of Cuda 9.1 after installing gpu driver, driver version of 390.48 reverted to 388.11.
- and so on.....

Again, I reinstalled Ubuntu by formatting and deleting everything in it.

2) I installed Cuda 9.1 and GPU driver version of 390.48 respectively (vice versa of above). This time, again, during the installation of CUDA 9.1, I got the error of fail of nvidia driver installation. So, I installed Nvidia driver version of 390.48 by removing pre-installed nvidia files and things. Still I got nothing except fails.

Please give some advices or solution for this problem. I need to install GPU driver 390.48 and CUDA 9.1. By the way, I have almost tried every solution on the internet, including Nvidia Guides. Where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried this one:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1025949/231142  ?  It does install the 390.48 drivers as well.

Comment: now, I am trying a method that a moderator from Nvidia recommended. If that works, I will post the solution. Still thanks.

Comment: If you get one that works, feel free to write that as your answer here.  It will definitely help others that could be experiencing the same issue.  :)

Comment: can you please help me about a step?  in the link below, there is 4.1.5.2 which says "Reboot into runlevel 3 by temporarily adding the number "3" and the word "nomodeset" to the end of the system's kernel boot parameters." what does it mean? what am i supposed to do? https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-quick-start-guide/index.html#ubuntu-x86_64-run

Comment: You need to edit the entry during startup by pressing the `e` key then finding the kernel line which I believe will have the `vmlinuz` on it, then you add the `3` and `nomodeset` to the end of that line.

Comment: I pressed the "e" button as you said. And I encountered a screen like this in the link (see the image) But I do not know what to do now. https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B1e7Au9XbXClWk9Sc2RydGUzanBtRFVyRHM3SkdTa19SUUUw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76301/discussion-between-ender-a-rencuzogullari-and-terrance).

Comment: It is the second from the bottom line there.  You just down arrow to that line, then right arrow to the end of the line then add on those two things then press Ctrl+X to boot.  My instructions don't go through any of this.  This sounds way to complicated even for me to do it that way.

Comment: so, should i just write 3 and give a space and write nomodeset ?

Comment: Yep that is what their instructions say to do.