# How to uninstall ppa + nvidia graphic and reinstall CUDA clean?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, ppa, cuda

I installed the `ppa graphic-drivers` and `nividia-390`, now it turned out I need the `CUDA` packages installed instead. The CUDA-part might be easy, just be doubleclick the .runfile... but:

What exact commands do I have to make, to uninstall the drivers and reinstall the current CUDA? Should I plug the screen back into the mainboard before?

(I read some tutorials on this, but I dont really get it totally....)

Comment: Try this one:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1025949/231142

Comment: It is good practice to link the tutorials you have tried so that others don't tell you to look at things you have tried

Comment: havent tried any tutorial yet, because the last time I tried to install CUDA, I was stuck in a login loop that I had to reinstall Ubuntu (tried ANY possible tutorial to end the loop)... for I just installed `ppa` and `390`... it's not just two commands and then install [CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html), is it?

Comment: The link I posted in the above comment does not use the `graphics-drivers` ppa.  It uses the actual NVIDIA developers ppa for the installation of CUDA 9.1 which in turn installs the nvidia-390 drivers with it.  Best to just copy and paste those commands to a terminal window.

Comment: works... :) So what about kernel issues, can I just run `sudo apt-get update` or do I have to take care of things? Just got a kernel update waiting in the update-manager, got 4.13.0-39-generic by now...

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work, thank you terrance!

`$ nvidia-smi
Tue May  8 01:00:35 2018

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.48                 Driver Version: 390.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8    11W / 200W |    218MiB /  6070MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+`

`+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1000      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           157MiB |
|    0      1760      G   compiz                                        40MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+`