# How can I verify correct CUDA is installed on my Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, deb, cuda

I want to install CUDA 8.0, but I got CUDA 7.5 when using the Nvidia provided `*.deb` file instead of the `*.run` installer.

I followed the instructions to install on the Nvidia website:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive

I installed:
`./cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb`

Instructions listed on website:

```
`sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-2-local_9.2.88-1_amd64.deb`
`sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-<version>/7fa2af80.pub`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install cuda`
```

I performed the **"Verify CUDA Installation"** step from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/799185

Results of running `nvcc --version`:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Results from when I run the installer step a second time:

```
$ sudo apt install cuda
[sudo] password for USER: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cuda is already the newest version (8.0.61-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
```

Definitely Something is incorrect because when I use the `*.run` version of the installer from the same page, it gives me the following `nvcc` output:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

Both machines have the same Nvidia Drivers installed:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Wed Jun 27 08:20:03 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

But the GPU's are different which should not matter because the machine giving issues has a newer graphics card in it. **Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti** versus 960M

To avoid conflicts and trouble with finding compatible drivers with Ubuntu 16.04, I just used the **additional drivers tab** on `software-properties-gtk`

Comment: I have setup CUDA 9.2 in 16.04LTS.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1025949/231142

Comment: Most likely you installed the 8.0 into a local directory,  and are picking up an old 7.5 install.  Also, what is your PATH set to? If that were not updated for the 8.0 location, that would cause the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Without login into GUI and after installation of cuda, reboot system.