# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code in CUDA Installation

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dependencies, cuda

***NOTE : Please care the EDIT 2. And you can see the FULL terminal output clearly on my answer under my question ***

I have tried to install and uninstall CUDA multiple times, but i got some errors this command.

I need to install Tensorflow with GPU. so CUDA is needed.
How can i solve this ?

```
$sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

cuda-cublas-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-cublas-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-cufft-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-cufft-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-curand-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-curand-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-cusolver-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-cusparse-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-libraries-9-0 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed
                      Depends: cuda-nvgraph-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed
                      Depends: cuda-cusolver-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed
                      Depends: cuda-cublas-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed
                      Depends: cuda-cufft-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed
                      Depends: cuda-curand-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed
                      Depends: cuda-cusparse-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed
                      Depends: cuda-npp-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-npp-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-npp-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-nvgraph-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-toolkit-9-0 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installed

cuda-visual-tools-9-0 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-9-0 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**EDIT 1 :** i have used Tensorflow with GPU for one year. I installed new version of CUDA 9.2 and then remove then again installed CUDA 9.0. Then this error occurred  Yes, my NVIDIA supports CUDA. using Tesla K40 and UBUNTU 16.04

**EDIT 2 :** I have followed the steps the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025931/no-hardware-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-kernel-4-4-0-78-generic/1025949#1025949). Everything was Ok, until installation step. It gives me the error :

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

What dpkg error?
How can i solve it ?
Any suggestion ?
Thank you

```
> $ sudo apt install cuda-9-0 Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree        Reading state information... Done The following
> packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
> libgcrypt20:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libsystemd0:i386 Use 'sudo apt
> autoremove' to remove them. The following additional packages will be
> installed:   cuda-cublas-9-0 cuda-cublas-dev-9-0 cuda-cufft-9-0
> cuda-cufft-dev-9-0 cuda-curand-9-0 cuda-curand-dev-9-0  
> cuda-cusolver-9-0 cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0 cuda-cusparse-9-0
> cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0 cuda-demo-suite-9-0   cuda-documentation-9-0
> cuda-libraries-9-0 cuda-libraries-dev-9-0 cuda-npp-9-0
> cuda-npp-dev-9-0 cuda-nvgraph-9-0   cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0
> cuda-nvml-dev-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0 cuda-runtime-9-0
> cuda-samples-9-0   cuda-toolkit-9-0 cuda-visual-tools-9-0 The
> following NEW packages will be installed:   cuda-9-0 cuda-cublas-9-0
> cuda-cublas-dev-9-0 cuda-cufft-9-0 cuda-cufft-dev-9-0 cuda-curand-9-0 
> cuda-curand-dev-9-0 cuda-cusolver-9-0 cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0
> cuda-cusparse-9-0 cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0   cuda-demo-suite-9-0
> cuda-documentation-9-0 cuda-libraries-9-0 cuda-libraries-dev-9-0
> cuda-npp-9-0   cuda-npp-dev-9-0 cuda-nvgraph-9-0 cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0
> cuda-nvml-dev-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0   cuda-runtime-9-0
> cuda-samples-9-0 cuda-toolkit-9-0 cuda-visual-tools-9-0 0 upgraded, 26
> newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded. Need to get 1.079 MB
> of archives. After this operation, 2.244 MB of additional disk space
> will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  Get:1
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64
> cuda-nvrtc-9-0 9.0.176-1 [6.348 kB] Get:2
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64
> cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 [9.334 B] Get:3
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64
> cuda-cusolver-9-0 9.0.176-1 [26,2 MB] Get:4
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64
> cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 [5.317 kB] Get:5 . . . . . . Get:26
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64
> cuda-9-0 9.0.176-1 [2.552 B]       Fetched 1.079 MB in 1min 35s (11,3
> MB/s)                                                                 
> (Reading database ... 298763 files and directories currently
> installed.) Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvrtc-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
> ... Unpacking cuda-nvrtc-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... dpkg: error processing
> archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvrtc-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is
> also in package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 Selecting previously
> unselected package cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-cusolver-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-cusolver-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusolver-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is
> also in package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 Selecting previously
> unselected package cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-cublas-9-0_9.0.176.3-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-cublas-9-0 (9.0.176.3-1) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-0_9.0.176.3-1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is
> also in package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 Selecting previously
> unselected package cuda-cublas-dev-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-cublas-dev-9-0_9.0.176.3-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-cublas-dev-9-0 (9.0.176.3-1) ... Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-cufft-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking cuda-cufft-9-0
> (9.0.176-1) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cufft-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
> trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is also in
> package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 No apport report written because
> MaxReports is reached already
>                                                               Selecting previously unselected package cuda-cufft-dev-9-0. Preparing
> to unpack .../cuda-cufft-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-cufft-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-curand-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking cuda-curand-9-0
> (9.0.176-1) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-curand-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is
> also in package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 No apport report written
> because MaxReports is reached already
>                                                               Selecting previously unselected package cuda-curand-dev-9-0. Preparing
> to unpack .../cuda-curand-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-curand-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-cusparse-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-cusparse-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusparse-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is
> also in package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 No apport report written
> because MaxReports is reached already
>                                                               Selecting previously unselected package cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0.
> Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-npp-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking cuda-npp-9-0
> (9.0.176-1) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-npp-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
> trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is also in
> package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 No apport report written because
> MaxReports is reached already
>                                                               Selecting previously unselected package cuda-npp-dev-9-0. Preparing to
> unpack .../cuda-npp-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-npp-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-nvgraph-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-nvgraph-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvgraph-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is
> also in package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 No apport report written
> because MaxReports is reached already
>                                                               Selecting previously unselected package cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0.
> Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Selecting previously
> unselected package cuda-samples-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-samples-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-samples-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Selecting previously unselected
> package cuda-documentation-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-documentation-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-documentation-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Selecting previously unselected
> package cuda-libraries-dev-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-libraries-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-libraries-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-nvml-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-nvml-dev-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvml-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64', which is
> also in package cuda-driver-dev-9-0 9.0.176-1 No apport report written
> because MaxReports is reached already
>                                                               Selecting previously unselected package cuda-visual-tools-9-0.
> Preparing to unpack .../cuda-visual-tools-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking cuda-visual-tools-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Selecting previously
> unselected package cuda-toolkit-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-toolkit-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-toolkit-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Selecting previously unselected
> package cuda-libraries-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-libraries-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-libraries-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Selecting previously unselected
> package cuda-runtime-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-runtime-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-runtime-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Selecting previously unselected
> package cuda-demo-suite-9-0. Preparing to unpack
> .../cuda-demo-suite-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> cuda-demo-suite-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Selecting previously unselected
> package cuda-9-0. Preparing to unpack .../cuda-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
> ... Unpacking cuda-9-0 (9.0.176-1) ... Errors were encountered while
> processing: 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvrtc-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusolver-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-0_9.0.176.3-1_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cufft-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-curand-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusparse-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-npp-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvgraph-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvml-dev-9-0_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb E:
> Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

***NOTE : Please care the EDIT 2. And you can see the FULL terminal output clearly on my answer under my question ***

Comment: Why did you remove 9.2?  Was it not working properly?  Sounds like it is a Repo problem you are having as to why it is not installing the files.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1025949/231142

Comment: have you tried `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: @Terrance , Since Tensorflow did not work, i removed 9.2

Comment: @cipricus , Yes i tried apt-get -f install

Comment: In the link I provided it does include the repo that contains CUDA versions 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2.  For 9.0 it would be `cuda-9-0` for the install.

Comment: @Terrance , $ sudo apt remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
....
Package 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-cublas-dev-9-0 : Depends: cuda-cublas-9-0 (>= 9.0.176) but it is not installable

Comment: That is only if you installed the nvidia-cuda-toolkit, which you did not do.   Did you step through the rest of it to at least get the repository set up?

Comment: @Terrance, I applied the steps . It gives error in installation step. I answered my post to show error. But i also want to ask about the source.list  /etc/apt/sources.list  . I encountered this file when i search on the Web.  I could not find this file.  This file is used for what ?

Comment: Before installing it, try running `sudo apt clean` to clear out any previous packages that might hold it up.  Then, after you get the `cuda-9-0` installed, run `sudo apt hold cuda-9-0` so that it doesn't try to upgrade to `cuda-9-2`.

Comment: The /etc/apt/source.list file is there for Ubuntu itself so that you can install programs from the repositories as that is what that file contains.  It should be in `/etc/apt` folder and should not be removed.

Comment: @Terrance, 1 week past, but still could not solve it. i don't have source.list in /etc/apt/, just have sources.list.save , i am not sure but maybe i deleted it wrongly. This missing file can cause this error ? It is true ?