# Cuda 9.2 is getting installed even after adding cuda 9.0 to list

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install cuda 9.0 instead of cuda 9.2 as the tensorflow is not compatible with it. I tried the following:

```
aims@aims:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i "cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64(1).deb"
(Reading database ... 212533 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64(1).deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu1604 (9.0.176-1) over (9.0.176-1) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1604 (9.0.176-1) ...
aims@aims:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                                          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                     
Hit:6 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release                                                                             
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                     
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                      
Hit:11 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                                           
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done 
aims@aims:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cuda-9-2 cuda-command-line-tools-9-2 cuda-compiler-9-2 cuda-cublas-9-2 cuda-cublas-dev-9-2 cuda-cudart-9-2 cuda-cudart-dev-9-2 cuda-cufft-9-2 cuda-cufft-dev-9-2 cuda-cuobjdump-9-2 cuda-cupti-9-2 cuda-curand-9-2 cuda-curand-dev-9-2 cuda-cusolver-9-2 cuda-cusolver-dev-9-2
  cuda-cusparse-9-2 cuda-cusparse-dev-9-2 cuda-demo-suite-9-2 cuda-documentation-9-2 cuda-driver-dev-9-2 cuda-drivers cuda-gdb-9-2 cuda-gpu-library-advisor-9-2 cuda-libraries-9-2 cuda-libraries-dev-9-2 cuda-license-9-2 cuda-memcheck-9-2 cuda-misc-headers-9-2 cuda-npp-9-2
  cuda-npp-dev-9-2 cuda-nsight-9-2 cuda-nvcc-9-2 cuda-nvdisasm-9-2 cuda-nvgraph-9-2 cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-2 cuda-nvml-dev-9-2 cuda-nvprof-9-2 cuda-nvprune-9-2 cuda-nvrtc-9-2 cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-2 cuda-nvtx-9-2 cuda-nvvp-9-2 cuda-runtime-9-2 cuda-samples-9-2 cuda-toolkit-9-2
  cuda-tools-9-2 cuda-visual-tools-9-2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda cuda-9-2 cuda-command-line-tools-9-2 cuda-compiler-9-2 cuda-cublas-9-2 cuda-cublas-dev-9-2 cuda-cudart-9-2 cuda-cudart-dev-9-2 cuda-cufft-9-2 cuda-cufft-dev-9-2 cuda-cuobjdump-9-2 cuda-cupti-9-2 cuda-curand-9-2 cuda-curand-dev-9-2 cuda-cusolver-9-2
  cuda-cusolver-dev-9-2 cuda-cusparse-9-2 cuda-cusparse-dev-9-2 cuda-demo-suite-9-2 cuda-documentation-9-2 cuda-driver-dev-9-2 cuda-drivers cuda-gdb-9-2 cuda-gpu-library-advisor-9-2 cuda-libraries-9-2 cuda-libraries-dev-9-2 cuda-license-9-2 cuda-memcheck-9-2
  cuda-misc-headers-9-2 cuda-npp-9-2 cuda-npp-dev-9-2 cuda-nsight-9-2 cuda-nvcc-9-2 cuda-nvdisasm-9-2 cuda-nvgraph-9-2 cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-2 cuda-nvml-dev-9-2 cuda-nvprof-9-2 cuda-nvprune-9-2 cuda-nvrtc-9-2 cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-2 cuda-nvtx-9-2 cuda-nvvp-9-2 cuda-runtime-9-2
  cuda-samples-9-2 cuda-toolkit-9-2 cuda-tools-9-2 cuda-visual-tools-9-2
0 upgraded, 48 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,145 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,642 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

As you can see that the Cuda 9.2 is getting reflected everywhere, even though I haven't added it. Previously I added but before going for 9.0 I have purged the cuda 9.2. But getting issues in installation. Kindly, help me.

Answer (score 1):

The repo http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/ contains 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2.

When you run `sudo apt install cuda` it will automatically pick the newest version.  Instead, you should specify the version during the installation:

```
sudo apt install cuda-9-0
```

then put a hold on it after it is installed so that it doesn't try to upgrade it to the newest version in that repository when you run `sudo apt upgrade` in the future:

```
sudo apt hold cuda-9-0
```

I have thrown together an answer for installing all 3 versions of CUDA in 16.04 at https://askubuntu.com/a/1025949/231142

Answer (score 0):

When you installed `cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64(1).deb` file then it added it's repository into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. Go to sources.list.d directory and delete them.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*
sudo apt update
```

Now it will not update to v9.2

Comment: Let me try it out

Comment: `root@aims:/home/aims/Downloads# sudo apt-get install cudaReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cuda
` Getting this error what to do?

Comment: What do you want to do ?

First install your cuda_9.0.deb file
Then delete repository files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
Then `sudo apt update`
That's all . Why are you trying `sudo apt install cuda` again. You have already installed. It will prevent the cuda from upgrading while running `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: I haven't install it dear can't you see in my question. I am trying to install 9.0 not 9.2. the version 9.2 was already installed and I removed it then tried installing 9.0