# Latest Nvidia driver- how long for PPA version?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Just purchased a new RTX 2080 Nvidia gpu and want to upgrade to the latest driver ASAP.

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04

On Nvidia's I see the latest driver with RTX support is

Version:    410.57

Release Date:   2018.9.19

Operating System:   Linux 64-bit

As a general rule I NEVER manually download and install Nvidia drivers.

How long does it normally take for the PPA version of latest Nvidia drivers to be available?

Comment: Overnight, NVIDIA posted those drivers.  I installed the new ones this morning on my system and they appear to be working great!  https://askubuntu.com/a/1025949/231142 they are at the bottom, but it also installs CUDA 10

Answer (score 0):

Add the [Michael Marley Staging (DO NOT USE) PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mamarley/+archive/ubuntu/staging) if you want the latest but this is a test PPA, Michael Marley is one of the guys working on the main Nvidia PPA so in time i'm sure he will update the main PPA or maybe you could contact him.

Comment: I have contacted Michael Marley via e-mail to let him know of my testing and this was his exact reply "Thanks for the testing!  I'm honestly not sure what the holdup in getting it copied to the main PPA is, but hopefully that will happen soon."