# How to download driver for new 2080ti with current 1080ti in place

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, additional-drivers

Just installed new 2080ti in the second PCEi slot in my motherboard

I think I physically installed it correctly because I get this when I run

```
ubuntu-drivers devices

mikedoho@RadMD:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E07sv00003842sd00002384bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001B06sv00003842sd00006698bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Not sure why model does come up with the second second GPU (I assume i need the right drivers). Currently my driver is 390.87. I was going to follow these directions : [No hardware working on Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.4.0-78-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025931/no-hardware-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-kernel-4-4-0-78-generic/1025949#1025949) but it looks like it will first delete my older driver.

1. Will this affect my 1080ti? - looking at NVIDIA website it looks like 410 supports 410 driver
2. is this the right set of directions for ubuntu 18

Comment: I was able to fix this issue.